# Do Chinese language users use 作心三日?

Tags: chengyu

This isn't exactly a question about the linguistic properties of the Chinese language, but something I'm just curious about.

Is 作心三日 a 成語 used in China? It's a very common Korean proverb, basically meaning that whatever someone puts their mind to, they can't last for a long period of time (literally translating to "the mindset you created, three days."

I'm just curious because I thought chengyu were pretty much the same across Chinese, Korean, and Japanese.

Comment: `I'm just curious because I thought chengyu were pretty much the same across Chinese, Korean, and Japanese.` There are a substantial amount which are shared, but Koreans and Japanese have also invented their own, which Chinese people may not understand (unless the *chengyu* is rather literal). Japanese 一石二鳥, for example, is not something you'd find in Chinese (actually it looks like a direct translation from English).

Comment: That's actually an interesting aspect of Korean and Japanese. Because Korea was colonized by Japan, there are many more similarities between the two languages than there are for Chinese. Many Japanese words using Chinese characters are also the same in Korean, but not the case for Chinese.

Comment: 一石二鳥 is a common Chinese idiom http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/3793/

Comment: I’m sure I’ve heard more traditional idioms than 一石二鳥, must be a relatively recent import. Anyway it’s undoubtedly ultimately from English.

Comment: @droooze I don't think the concept of 一石二鳥 was imported from English, Chinese already have a similar idiom 一箭雙雕 . The two terms are similar but with subtle difference. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/difference-between-these-two-phrases-for-killing-two-birds-with-one-stone-%e4%b8%80%e7%ae%ad%e5%8f%8c/21052?r=SearchResults&s=1|15.2515#21052

Comment: @TangHo the *concept* may not have been imported from English, but the phrase definitely is. You can’t find 一石二鳥 in literature until modern times.

Answer (score 2):

No, but there is a colloquial proverb (俗语) [in this vein](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%89%E5%A4%A9%E6%89%93%E9%B1%BC%EF%BC%8C%E4%B8%A4%E5%A4%A9%E6%99%92%E7%BD%91):

> 三天打鱼，两天晒网
>
> sān tiān dǎ yú, liǎng tiān shài wǎng

A more modern turn of phrase is:

> [五分钟热度](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%BA%94%E5%88%86%E9%92%9F%E7%83%AD%E5%BA%A6)
>
> wǔ fēnzhōng rèdù

... literally "five minutes of zeal / enthusiasm".

Comment: Isn’t it 三分钟 and not 5 min?

Comment: I've heard of the 三分钟 version as well - but it strikes me as very modern.

Comment: Attention spans are dropping